# How to pass item of h:dataTable with ResultSetDataModel to action method?

Tags: jsf, datatable, el, resultset

I have a code, which when I try to access(through a JSF datatable, with a commandButton) it gives me the following error:

The error I am getting is:

> javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /page.xhtml @66,93 action="#{example.addToCart(p)}": Method not found: class managedbean.example.addToCart(javax.faces.model.ResultSetDataModel$ResultSetMap)

Here is the xhtml code for the datatable.

```
                <h:dataTable value="#{example.info}" var="p" summary="Product list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px" class="tablef table container">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Product name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.itemName}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Product Description"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.itemDesc}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Product Price"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.price}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Add To Cart"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandButton action="#{example.addToCart(p)}" value="Add Item"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

Here is the java code that is meant to be accessed and print to console.

```
    public void addToCart(HashMap product) {
        System.out.println("This is a test: " + product.entrySet());
    }
```

The original data being passed into the datatable is a ResultSet(this is what variable p is). I get a very similar error message when using ResultSet as the param type instead of HashMap.

I have tried different paramater types, the only one that has worked is an object, which im not sure how to then use in order to access the key:values.

I expected it to take the information and then print it to console.

The result is an error that is displayed above.